# How do I get SQL LEFT with alias into bookshelf?

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I need this `SQL` (works perfectly in mysql console) :

```
SELECT LEFT(authors.last_name,1) AS first_char
```

In `"bookshelf.js"`.

While I get this far:

```
let result = await qb.column('last_name').select().from('authors').as('first_char');
```

I can't get

```
let result = await qb.column('last_name').select('LEFT(authors.last_name,1)').from('authors').as('first_char');
```

this going.

It results in the following error:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'LEFT(authors.last_name,1)' in 'field list'
```

which does not make sense to me, because the column `authors.last_name` is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.select()` protects against SQL injection so you can't just pass random SQL to it and expect it to work. You need to use raw expressions for that:

```
qb.column('last_name').select(qb.raw('LEFT(authors.last_name,1)')).from('authors').as('first_char');
```

And on that note, technically this isn't a bookshelf question since the query builder is just knex.